# Find all solutions to the equation over field $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$

Tags: finite-fields

So for the first part of the question, I have to find the solutions to:

$\ x^2+4x+3=0$
over $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$
I have found these to be $X=5,7,13$ and $15$, just by using standard method to solve a quadratic over a field.
However the next part of the question is to find

$\ x^{128}+4x+3=0$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{127}$
How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Note that every nonzero element of $\Bbb Z_{127}$ has multiplicative order dividing $126$.

Comment: Note that $\Bbb{Z}_{16}$ is NOT a field. The first equation is equivalent to $(x+2)^2=1$ though. So your set of solutions  follows from knowing the four solutions of $y^2=1$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{16}$. OTOH $\Bbb{Z}_{127}$ is a field as $127$ is a prime.

Answer (score 1):

Hint For the first question : Use $x^2+4x+3=(x+1)(x+3)$

Hint for the second question : In $Z_{127}$ you have $x^{127}=x$ for all $x$